# Installing IDE and framework from RPMs on CentOs6.6, dependencies not met?

Tags: redhawksdr

I am running CentOS6.6, 64 bit.  I followed instructions in section [2.3.2](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch2.html#x4-110002.3) to install dependencies, no problem.  But in section [2.4](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch2.html#x4-140002.4) I ran into problems after trying the command `sudo yum install --nogpgcheck *.rpm`.  I get lots of errors like Requires libomnithread.so.3, libomniORB4.so.1, liblog4cxx.so.10, libCOS4.so.1, liblog4cxx.so.1, etc....

Comment: Forgot to mention, after each missing library file there is an set of parentheses and the characters (64bit) in parentheses.  Are the commands I'm following only installing 32 bit version of dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you do not have the epel repository installed, as shown in section 2.3.1.  On a CentOS6.6 system, the following command would work to install the latest epel release repository.

```
yum install -y epel-release
```

The dependencies will now be found (within the epel repository you've added) and automatically pulled down.